# UICollectionView: Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimations]

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, uicollectionview, assertions

I'm getting this error in my app:

*** Assertion failure in `-[UICollectionView _endItemAnimations]`, /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2372/UICollectionView.m:2801

It happens in my `-controllerDidChangeContent:` method on this line:

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{...}];
```

Does anyone know what causes this? My code is closely based off of https://gist.github.com/4440c1cba83318e276bb and I'm at a loss.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

These types of assertions get thrown as exceptions.  Wrap the batch updates in a try/catch and dump the exception description.  It will tell you exactly what it doesn't like about your call.

In other words:

```
    @try
    {
        [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{...}];
    }
    @catch (NSException *except)
    {
        NSLog(@"DEBUG: failure to batch update.  %@", except.description);
    }
```

Comment: Good option for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I bet it's because of that your

```
-controllerDidChangeContent
```

is being called in background thread multiple times, and performBatchUpdates is still working when another thread calls it, so it leads to incorrect behavior.

Solution - try to wrap it in @synchronized or using NSLocks

Comment: It was definitely being called on the main thread so this wasn't the issue

Answer (score 1):

The issue was not setting the FRC delegate to nil on view didDisappear.

Comment: Cheers!  That was it!  Setting FRC to nil on viewDidDisappear and reassigning to self of viewWillAppear solved my similar issue.

Comment: What does FRC stand for? :-|

Comment: @Kalle: FRC = Fetched Results Controller